# Is it possible to access the CSS counter value of the parent element from a child element?

Tags: css, counter

I have a `div` element where I set the counter. And I insert a label using the `:before` selector. Now, I want to use the counter of the `div` element inside the `h1` element which is a child of the said div element. I am doing this because I want the book mark of the h1 to contain the counter of its parent.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: chapter 0;
}

div {
  counter-increment: chapter;
}

div:before {
  content: "Chapter " counter(chapter)" ";
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  content: counter(chapter) content();
  bookmark-label: "Chapter" counter(chapter) content();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <h2>Heading 2</h2>
  <h3>Heading 3</h3>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <h2>Heading 2</h2>
  <h3>Heading 3</h3>
</div>
```

**Actual Result**

The counter does not get prepended to the h1 content and to the bookmark.

**Expected Result**

Bookmark should show the div counter.

Comment: What is this `bookmark-label` property you are using?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Here is what I know about it - It's for CSS-based PDF rendering engines. This property is available in the paged media CSS. https://www.script-tutorials.com/css-ref/bookmark-label/

Comment: I'm not familiar with what `bookmark-*` properties do so I'm not 100% sure on what you're asking to do (and the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/) has several errors just from 1 min of reading so far), but is this what you're looking to do? https://jsfiddle.net/u0opzL7t/ Show the chapter # from the div in front of the `<h1>`? Keep in mind the spec there is a Working Draft, so properties within it should not be used in production.

Comment: Agreeing with @TylerH -- couldn't find any references to a `bookmark-label` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/)...

Comment: @AlexanderNied here is the reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#bookmark-label

Comment: @TylerH sorry if the sample I shared contains errors. Is there a way to set the counter to h1 without using `::before` pseudo selector. In my sample, I included `content: counter(chapter) content();` only because there is no way to render the bookmark in stackoverflow.

Comment: @Antony It's not the sample of code you shared that has errors (well, it might, but I dunno about them if there are any), it is the *official spec* -- it has some examples where it says "this will produce x" but it produces "y" instead of "x"... this is exactly the kind of reason to not use properties from a spec whose status is "Working-Draft". At the very least, I'd wait for something to hit "Candidate Recommendation" status before using them in production (of course, that doesn't mean you can't ask about them on SO... but in this case, it seems the spec isn't really ready yet).

Comment: @Antony As far as not being able to render the bookmark in SO, I can't get it to render anywhere... I'm not sure it's generally ready for use.

Comment: content:''; should only be used on pseudo before/after , it is not made to overwrite the content of a tag, even if chrome did it for a long time (i guess it is fixed by now)  ... you could do  `body {content:'';}` and chrome users had nothing to see ...